# Use regex to parse string into groups

Tags: python, regex

I cant seem to get regex to work with the following example.  Basically I would like to parse 4 groups from a string such as below:

```
test.this
test[extra].this
test[extra].this{data}
test.this{data}
```

I would like to get the answer as such, for the examples above respectively:

```
val1='test', val2=None, val3='this', val4=None
val1='test', val2='extra', val3='this', val4=None
val1='test', val2='extra', val3='this', val4='data'
val1='test', val2=None, val3='this', val4='data'
```

I tried this but it's not working:

```
import re

tests = ["test.this",
         "test[extra].this",
         "test[extra].this{data}",
         "test.this{data}",]

for test in tests:
    m = re.match(r'^([^\[\.]+)(?:\[([^\]]+)])(?:\.([^{]+){)([^}]+)?$', test)
    if m:
        print(test, '->', m[1], m[2], m[3], m[4])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If only the second and fourth groups are optional, you may use:

```
^([^\[\.]+)(?:\[([^\]]+)])?\.([^{\r\n]+)(?:{([^}\r\n]+)})?$
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gh55I6/1)**.

Note that `\r` and `\n` were added in the negated character classes of the third and fourth groups to avoid going beyond the end of the line. If you're only using single-line strings, that won't be necessary.

Comment: Yes this works, but yea I think you meant first and third is required, not optional.  But yea this answer works.  Will review your answer on how it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
import re

tests = ["test.this",
     "test[extra].this",
     "test[extra].this{data}",
     "test.this{data}"]

pat = re.compile(r'(\w+)([\[])?(\w+)?([\]])?\.(\w+){?(\w+)?')
for test in tests:
    x = pat.search(test)
    print(x.group(1),x.group(3),x.group(5),x.group(6))
```

**(\w+)** -> captures **test**

**([\[])?** -> captures **[**

**(\w+)?** -> captures **extra**

**([\]])?** -> captures **]**

**(\w+)** -> captures **this**

**(\w+)?** -> captures **data**

Comment: Question, how is '(\w+)?' not capturing '}' with data? I mean I know your solution works, just trying to understand how '}' is being ignored there

Comment: contents inside the () braces are only captured in the grouping. since **\w** looks for only alphabets, digits, and underscores. Hence '}' is ignored.